# Android/JAVA/SQLite No me reconoce una columna

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-sqlite

Estoy haciendo una app para Android en Java tratando de leer los datos de una base de datos.

Tengo una clase DDBB_Helper que gestiona la creación de la base de datos:

```
package com.geologyappliacions.mine180;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class BBDD_Helper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "mineralesEs.db";

    public BBDD_Helper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(EstructuraBBDD.SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES);
    }

    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL(EstructuraBBDD.SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void onDowngrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        onUpgrade(db, oldVersion, newVersion);
    }

}
```

También tengo una clase EstructuraBBDD que estructura la base de datos y crea la tabla que pretendo leer:

```
package com.geologyappliacions.mine180;

public class EstructuraBBDD {

    private EstructuraBBDD() {}

    public static final String NOMBRE_TABLA = "mineralesEs";
    public static final String COLUMNA1 = "id";
    public static final String COLUMNA2 = "color";
    public static final String COLUMNA3 = "nombre1";
    public static final String COLUMNA4 = "nombre2";
    public static final String COLUMNA5 = "nombre3";
    public static final String COLUMNA6 = "imagen";
    public static final String COLUMNA7 = "grupo";
    public static final String COLUMNA8 = "tipo";
    public static final String COLUMNA9 = "clase";
    public static final String COLUMNA10 = "formula";
    public static final String COLUMNA11 = "sistema";
    public static final String COLUMNA12 = "amb1";
    public static final String COLUMNA13 = "amb2";
    public static final String COLUMNA14 = "amb3";
    public static final String COLUMNA15 = "amb4";
    public static final String COLUMNA16 = "amb5";
    public static final String COLUMNA17 = "amb6";
    public static final String COLUMNA18 = "amb7";
    public static final String COLUMNA19 = "amb8";
    public static final String COLUMNA20 = "amb9";
    public static final String COLUMNA21 = "amb10";
    public static final String COLUMNA22 = "habito";
    public static final String COLUMNA23 = "color";
    public static final String COLUMNA24 = "diafanidad";
    public static final String COLUMNA25 = "brillo";
    public static final String COLUMNA26 = "raya";
    public static final String COLUMNA27 = "densidad";
    public static final String COLUMNA28 = "dureza";
    public static final String COLUMNA29 = "exfoliacion";
    public static final String COLUMNA30 = "fractura";
    public static final String COLUMNA31 = "autor";
    public static final String COLUMNA32 = "link";
    
    private static final String TEXT_TYPE = "TEXT";
    private static final String COMMA_SEP = ",";
    public static final String SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES =
        "CREATE TABLE " + EstructuraBBDD.NOMBRE_TABLA + " (" +
                EstructuraBBDD.COLUMNA1 + TEXT_TYPE +
                EstructuraBBDD.COLUMNA2 + TEXT_TYPE +
                EstructuraBBDD.COLUMNA3 + TEXT_TYPE +
                EstructuraBBDD.COLUMNA4 + TEXT_TYPE +
                EstructuraBBDD.COLUMNA5 + TEXT_TYPE +
                EstructuraBBDD.COLUMNA6 + TEXT_TYPE +
                EstructuraBBDD.COLUMNA7 + TEXT_TYPE +
                EstructuraBBDD.COLUMNA8 + TEXT_TYPE +
                EstructuraBBDD.COLUMNA9 + TEXT_TYPE +
                EstructuraBBDD.COLUMNA10 + TEXT_TYPE +
                EstructuraBBDD.COLUMNA11 + TEXT_TYPE +
                EstructuraBBDD.COLUMNA12 + TEXT_TYPE +
                EstructuraBBDD.COLUMNA13 + TEXT_TYPE +
                EstructuraBBDD.COLUMNA14 + TEXT_TYPE +
                EstructuraBBDD.COLUMNA15 + TEXT_TYPE +
                EstructuraBBDD.COLUMNA16 + TEXT_TYPE +
                EstructuraBBDD.COLUMNA17 + TEXT_TYPE +
                EstructuraBBDD.COLUMNA18 + TEXT_TYPE +
                EstructuraBBDD.COLUMNA19 + TEXT_TYPE +
                EstructuraBBDD.COLUMNA20 + TEXT_TYPE +
                EstructuraBBDD.COLUMNA21 + TEXT_TYPE +
                EstructuraBBDD.COLUMNA22 + TEXT_TYPE +
                EstructuraBBDD.COLUMNA23 + TEXT_TYPE +
                EstructuraBBDD.COLUMNA24 + TEXT_TYPE +
                EstructuraBBDD.COLUMNA25 + TEXT_TYPE +
                EstructuraBBDD.COLUMNA26 + TEXT_TYPE +
                EstructuraBBDD.COLUMNA27 + TEXT_TYPE +
                EstructuraBBDD.COLUMNA28 + TEXT_TYPE +
                EstructuraBBDD.COLUMNA29 + TEXT_TYPE +
                EstructuraBBDD.COLUMNA30 + TEXT_TYPE +
                EstructuraBBDD.COLUMNA31 + TEXT_TYPE +
                EstructuraBBDD.COLUMNA32 + TEXT_TYPE + ")";

     public static final String SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES =
             "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + EstructuraBBDD.NOMBRE_TABLA;
}
```

Por último, en MainActivity relleno una fila de la base de datos para tratar de leer los datos en un ListView.

```
package com.geologyappliacions.mine180;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final BBDD_Helper dbHelper = new BBDD_Helper(this);
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(EstructuraBBDD.COLUMNA1,"1");
        values.put(EstructuraBBDD.COLUMNA2,"#a2ceef");
        values.put(EstructuraBBDD.COLUMNA3,"oro");
        values.put(EstructuraBBDD.COLUMNA4,"oro");
        values.put(EstructuraBBDD.COLUMNA5,"oro");
        values.put(EstructuraBBDD.COLUMNA6,"oro.png");
        values.put(EstructuraBBDD.COLUMNA7,"No silicatos");
        values.put(EstructuraBBDD.COLUMNA8,"Elementos nativos.");
        values.put(EstructuraBBDD.COLUMNA9,"Oro.");
        values.put(EstructuraBBDD.COLUMNA10,"Au");
        values.put(EstructuraBBDD.COLUMNA11,"Cúbico");
        values.put(EstructuraBBDD.COLUMNA12,"Hidrotermal");
        values.put(EstructuraBBDD.COLUMNA13,"Asociado a venas de cuarzo.");
        values.put(EstructuraBBDD.COLUMNA14,"Sedimentario");
        values.put(EstructuraBBDD.COLUMNA15,"Placeres.");
        values.put(EstructuraBBDD.COLUMNA16,"Magmático");
        values.put(EstructuraBBDD.COLUMNA17,"Yacimientos IOCG.");
        values.put(EstructuraBBDD.COLUMNA18,"no");
        values.put(EstructuraBBDD.COLUMNA19,"");
        values.put(EstructuraBBDD.COLUMNA20,"no");
        values.put(EstructuraBBDD.COLUMNA21,"");
        values.put(EstructuraBBDD.COLUMNA22,"Cristales octaédricos. Arborescente, escamoso, en pepitas.");
        values.put(EstructuraBBDD.COLUMNA23,"Amarillo característico.");
        values.put(EstructuraBBDD.COLUMNA24,"Opaco.");
        values.put(EstructuraBBDD.COLUMNA25,"Metálico.");
        values.put(EstructuraBBDD.COLUMNA26,"Amarilla característica.");
        values.put(EstructuraBBDD.COLUMNA27,"19.3");
        values.put(EstructuraBBDD.COLUMNA28,"2.75");
        values.put(EstructuraBBDD.COLUMNA29,"---");
        values.put(EstructuraBBDD.COLUMNA30,"Astillosa, dentada.");
        values.put(EstructuraBBDD.COLUMNA31,"(1)The Arkenstone. iRocks.com.");  
        values.put(EstructuraBBDD.COLUMNA32,"http://www.irocks.com/minerals/specimen/46020"); 
 

    db.insert(EstructuraBBDD.NOMBRE_TABLA,null,values);
    db.close();

    ImageButton btnG = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.bGallery);
    btnG.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Guia.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        });

    }
 }
```

La línea que da error es esta: `db.insert(EstructuraBBDD.NOMBRE_TABLA,null,values);`:

```
E/SQLiteLog: (1) table mineralesEs has no column named fractura in "INSERT INTO mineralesEs(fractura,brillo,dureza,habito,imagen,formula,id,amb1,amb2,amb3,amb4,amb5,amb6,amb7,amb8,amb9,link,raya,tipo,amb10,autor,clase,color,gr
E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting fractura=Astillosa, dentada. brillo=Metálico. dureza=2.75 habito=Cristales octaédricos. Arborescente, escamoso, en pepitas. imagen=oro.png formula=Au id=1 amb1=Hidrotermal amb2=Asociado a venas de cuarzo. amb3=Sedimentario amb4=Placeres. amb5=Magmático amb6=Yacimientos IOCG. amb7=no amb8= amb9=no link=http://www.irocks.com/minerals/specimen/46020 raya=Amarilla característica. tipo=Elementos nativos. amb10= autor=(1)The Arkenstone. iRocks.com. clase=Oro. color=Amarillo característico. grupo=No silicatos densidad=19.3 diafanidad=Opaco. exfoliacion=--- sistema=Cúbico nombre1=oro nombre2=oro nombre3=oro
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table mineralesEs has no column named fractura (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: INSERT INTO mineralesEs(fractura,brillo,dureza,habito,imagen,formula,id,amb1,amb2,amb3,amb4,amb5,amb6,amb7,amb8,amb9,link,raya,tipo,amb10,autor,clase,color,grupo,densidad,diafanidad,exfoliacion,sistema,nombre1,nombre2,nombre3) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1045)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:652)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:590)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:61)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:33)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1699)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1570)
    at com.geologyappliacions.mine180.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:54)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7994)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7978)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Soy nuevo programando en Android y no sé si este error es porque ejecuto la aplicación en el AVD. ¿Está bien estucturado mi código? Estoy siguiendo el tutorial de Android Developer. Al compilar el .apk no se cuelga, es lo que me mosquea.

Comment: Como consejo te diría que llames a las columnas por su nombre, es decir a la columna 1 llamale ID, algo que sea identificativo, te será más fácil detectar posible errores en el futuro

Comment: Y el error que sale es que hay un campo que no estás teniendo en cuenta que es el campo FRATURA

Comment: @RoyalUp Entiendo el log, pero yo inserto en los values `values.put((EstructuraBBDD.COLUMNA30,"Astillosa, dentada.");`como columna 30 que tengo declarada `public static final String COLUMNA30 = "fractura";`. No entiendo dónde está el error.

Comment: Puede ser por la coma?

Comment: has mirado que la columna esa ya existe? Se llama de la misma manera que la has llamado?

Comment: A qué coma te refieres?

Comment: @RoyalUp A que el texto que se almacena o trato de almacenar tiene una coma "Astillosa, dentada", y mi coma separator es la coma

Comment: @RoyalUp Sí, está creada la columna con ese nombre `public static final String COLUMNA30 = "fractura";`

Comment: No, la coma no es. La he quitado y sigue dando error.

Comment: Es que estabas diciendo que estás intentando leer una tabla, es verdad que en tu código se llama fractura, pero en la tabla original quizás tengo otro nombre

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como lo comentas, el error indica que la tabla `mineralesEs` no contiene la columna llamada `fractura`

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table mineralesEs has no
> column named fractura (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: INSERT
> INTO
> mineralesEs(fractura,brillo,dureza,habito,imagen,formula,id,amb1,amb2,amb3,amb4,amb5,amb6,amb7,amb8,amb9,link,raya,tipo,amb10,autor,clase,color,grupo,densidad,diafanidad,exfoliacion,sistema,nombre1,nombre2,nombre3)
> VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)

Al revisar tu script para generar la tabla este contiene la columna `fractura` , en este caso el problema es que se genero una estructura la cual no tiene el campo, como esta generada la tabla ya no se vuelve a crear, tienes 2 opciones:

- Eliminar la aplicaciòn y volver a subirla para que el script genere nuevamente la correcta estructura.
- En la clase que extiende de `SQLiteOpenHelper` aumentar el numero de la versiòn para que vuelva a crear la estructura correca de la tabla.

public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

Esto llamarà al mètodo `onUpgrade()` automàticamente que eliminara la tabla y la creara nuevamente.

```
  public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL(EstructuraBBDD.SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES);
        onCreate(db);
    }
```

---

Tambiên tienes un problema en el script, falta la "," para separar los campos en el script, realiza el siguiente cambio, agrega una coma y un espacio al inicio en la variable `TEXT_TYPE` y en el último campo solo define su tipo como `TEXT`

```
private static final String TEXT_TYPE = " TEXT,";
```

Revisa el cambio :

```
package com.geologyappliacions.mine180;

public class EstructuraBBDD {

    private EstructuraBBDD() {}
    ...
    ...
    ...
private static final String TEXT_TYPE = " TEXT,";
    private static final String COMMA_SEP = ",";
    public static final String SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES =
        "CREATE TABLE " + EstructuraBBDD.NOMBRE_TABLA + " (" +
                EstructuraBBDD.COLUMNA1 + TEXT_TYPE +
...
...
...
                EstructuraBBDD.COLUMNA31 + TEXT_TYPE +
                EstructuraBBDD.COLUMNA32 + " TEXT " + ")";
```

Comment: Gracias lo pruebo mañana y te digo pero me parece que debe ser algo así.

Comment: Excelente  
Universal_learner
, saludos.

Comment: Buenos días. Comunicarte que he puesto de version 2 y sigue dando el mismo error.

Comment: Funciona gracias era eso.